# ClickOnce not passing second Uri

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, clickonce

We have a WPF application, which uses  `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` class to make it `singleton`; and is deployed using `ClickOne`. Whenever we wanted to execute this exe, we invoke it through Uri (deployed directory in server with query string). All works fine only for first instance of this application.

**Problem**: ClickOnce always passes the first Uri every time the single-instance application is activated regardless of what Uri is being passed. In addition, the `StartupNextInstanceEventArgs` is not populated for any subsequent instantiation of same application.

Has anyone had this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well so far I haven't got any concrete answer for my question. Therefore, I decided implement a different solution which is mentioned [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/single-instance-wpf-application). Unfortunately, the original issue hold true in both approach. So i decided to do a workaround on top of the second approach (see the url) to solve this until I have a clean solution.

**Workaround**

1. Modified entry point (Main) to include a functionality, which saves the incoming activation uri to app config file. You must keep this position at which you save the value since it tended to override with old activation uri somewhere down the line. Remember this is my issue.

   ```
    public static void Main()
    {
      string uri;
      StartupHelpers.SetConfigurationValue("ActivationUri", (StartupHelpers.HasTriggeredFromUrl(out uri)) ? uri : string.Empty);    
      if (SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance(Unique))
           {
            var application = new App();
            application.Run();
            SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
           }
    }
   ```
2. Now implement the interface (ISingletonInstanceApp) as below.

   ```
       public bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList<string> args)
       {
           var uri = new  Uri(StartupHelpers.GetConfigurationValue("ActivationUri"));
           int queryString = 0;
           if (StartupHelpers.IsTriggeredFromWLink(uri, out queryString))
           {
           //in my case I have a function LoadPage which take 
           //some parameter to populate UI.   Your case might be
           //totally  different. However, the idea is on how we
           //could grab   running instance and pass value into
           // it to do something different.

               ((YourMainWindow) (Current.MainWindow)).LoadPage(queryString.ToString());

           }

           // Bring window to foreground
           if (this.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
               {
               this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
               }

           this.MainWindow.Activate();

           return true;
           }
   ```
3. Helper to get/set config values.

   ```
       public static class StartupHelpers
   {
         public static bool HasTriggeredFromUrl(out string uri)
          {
           try
           {
               uri = string.Empty;
               var activeUri = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri;
               uri = activeUri != null ? activeUri.ToString() : string.Empty;
               return true;
           }
           catch (InvalidDeploymentException inv)
           {
               uri = string.Empty;
               return false;
           }
       }

       public static bool IsTriggeredFromLink(Uri activationUri, out int queryStringValue)
       {
           queryStringValue = 0;
           var hasTriggeredFromLink = true;
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activationUri.Query) ||
               HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(activationUri.Query).Count <= 0)
               hasTriggeredFromLink = false;
           else
           {
               if (!int.TryParse(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(activationUri.Query)[0], out queryStringValue))
                   throw new Exception("Invalid startup argument found from web site.");

           }

           return hasTriggeredFromLink;
       }

       public static bool SetConfigurationValue(string key, string value)
       {
           try
           {
               Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
               appConfig.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
               appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
               ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }
           return true;
       }

       public static string GetConfigurationValue(string key)
       {
           try
           {
               Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
               ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
               return appConfig.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late answer but I happened to stumble upon this while looking into forcing an application to a single instance.

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want a single instance app which takes command line parameters. The second time the app is attempted to be run, you just want to keep the first instance but pass the second set of command line parameters to it.

In this case, why not host a WCF service in your WPF application with an appropriate method which is what you pass these parameters to instead. The web page that is utilizing the ClickOnce then just calls this service method with the parameters it would have passed.